# Windows Open With Dialog from Java

Tags: java, windows, processbuilder

I need to call the Windows Open With dialog from my Java code. I used to use this line:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("RUNDLL32.EXE SHELL32.DLL,OpenAs_RunDLL " + absolute_file_path)
```

However, with Java JDK 20, my compiler now complains that form of exec is deprecated. I see that ProcessBuilder is the recommended replacement, and I've been able to use it for other Windows command-line execution. However, I've been unable to get this to work for Open With:

```
ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder("RUNDLL32.EXE","SHELL32.DLL,OpenAs_RunDLL", absolute_file_path);
builder.start();
```

What do I need to do to get this to work with ProcessBuilder?

Comment: My first question would be: why are you not using `java.awt.Desktop` to [do this](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/Desktop.html#open(java.io.File))?

Comment: Guess I'm not being clear, g00se. I'm not trying to open the actual file (which Desktop does just fine). I'm trying to get Windows to open its "Open With" dialog, which offers users a choice of installed applications that can open the specified file.

Comment: Ah right. First call `builder.inheritIO();` before `start()`

Comment: Alas, g00se, didn't help. Still not seeing the dialog.

Comment: Give this a try. You might need the full path to powershell: `ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder("powershell", "Start-Process", "-Verb openas", "-FilePath", absolute_file_path).inheritIO();builder.start();`

Comment: Well, g00se, PowerShell was the key. This is what worked:                 ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder("powershell", "RUNDLL32.EXE SHELL32.DLL,OpenAs_RunDLL " + absolute_file_path);
                process = builder.start();

Comment: I would say there would be more future in the other invocation if you can make it work.